# upload with ftp to web api

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.0

I created a web api in asp.net core 3,
I made it possible to send files to the web api,
I'm looking for a way to upload a file to the web api by Ftp,
I don't know if it's possible,
If there is a way to do this, please help me

Comment: Hi Masha. Web API's tend to use HTTP(s), FTP is a totally different protocol, so no, you can't.  However there are probably solutions to what you are actually trying to achieve, so why not explain what you want to achieve and people can help with a solution.